# How do I get the right entry data based on locale and slug?

Tags: localization

My site has 2 locales: `en_us` and `nl_nl`. I also have a Structure section called Pages, which targets both locales. For each locale, the section has an Entry URL Format:

- en_us: `en/{slug}`
- nl_nl: `nl/{slug}`

The Entry Template setting for the section is `pages/_entry`, and there is a template there.

Now, for an entry with the slug `home` for both locales, the URI `nl/home` gives me the correct page, but `en/home` gives me a 404.

Is my setup wrong? Do I need to explicitly create `nl` and `en` template folders?

Comment: Have you setup the `CRAFT_LOCALE` correctly? http://buildwithcraft.com/help/localization

Comment: Hadn't set it at all. That helps.

Comment: Note to self: locale should be exact. `en_us != en` and `nl_nl != nl`.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the [`CRAFT_LOCALE`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/php-constants#craft-locale) isn't set correctly. There is an in-depth [knowledge article here](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/localization).

To solve this, you could add a conditional to the `/public/index.php`:

```php
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../craft';

//Locale
if ( preg_match("/\/nl\//i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) { //Check if /nl/ is in the uri
    define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'nl_nl');
}
else {
    define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'en_us');
}
```