# localization is NOT working

Tags: localization, nginx

i'm running centos 6.6, nginx 1.7.7, mysql and php-fpm (i believe 5.5.3) and craft 2.4.2669.

i enable a new language and let all the background tasks complete (the default data copied to the templates is english) and followed the steps here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide

the localized home page works fine.

i've tried this, with a little luck: 
[Locales sub directories on Nginx](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/780/locales-sub-directories-on-nginx)

my language picker doesn't work right: where i send users to the localized version of the page if it exists (otherwise they go to the home page). same code works fine on my local dev (mamp). similar to: [How can I build a language switcher?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-can-i-build-a-language-switcher)

anyone have any luck using localization on craft with nginx? help asap please.

thanks,
jeremy

Comment: Currently using localisation and similar menu on nginx. walkthrough: http://webstoemp.com/blog/craft-multilingual-websites-tips/ So you are using subdirectories for languages, correct ? Using the standard nginx config coming with craft ? Did you copy it to all lggs subdir ?