# Translated entry page can not be found (404)

Tags: localization, database, request

I have installed and built a website using Craft CMS (with latest updates). I'm running this Craft installation on a Homestead virtual machine.

When I enabled localization and translated entries in a structure section, the url opens a 404 page.

In my setup I have two locales `nb_no` and `en`. Both locales are enabled for the section `artists`. Both locales are using the same url structure for entries: `artists\{slug}`.

My configuration for `siteUrl` is as follows:

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'http://page.craft.dev/en/',
    'nb_no' => 'http://page.craft.dev',
),
```

Debbuging the problem I see that there is an error in `TemplatesController.php`. In the function `actionRender($template, array $variables = array())` the value of `$template` is `en/artists/andre-bratten` instead of `artists/_entry` as is the case for the main language entry.

Further exploration of logs shows me that Craft executes the following query which returns no result:

```
[09:30:32.080][trace][system.db.CDbCommand]
Querying SQL: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`
FROM `craft_elements` `elements`
JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = elements.id
WHERE (elements_i18n.uri = :uri) AND (elements_i18n.locale = :locale) AND (elements_i18n.enabled = 1) AND (elements.enabled = 1) AND (elements.archived = 0). Bound with :uri='en/artists/andre-bratten', :locale='nb_no'
in /home/vagrant/web/ekko/craft/app/services/ElementsService.php (151)
in /home/vagrant/web/ekko/craft/app/etc/web/UrlManager.php (281)
in /home/vagrant/web/ekko/craft/app/etc/web/UrlManager.php (140)
```

In my database `elements_i18n` table the entries both have `uri = "artists/andre-bratten"` and different locales.

As well there is a problem with wrong locale in the sql query (`nb_no` instead of `en`). I set `CRAFT_LOCALE` to `en` in the `public\en\index.php` file.

As I'm rereading this I think that there could be a problem with resolving the correct path (i.e. removing `en/` from the front) when the locale is set incorrectly. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

---

### Update

I found out that when I access `http:\\page.craft.dev\en\` I am loading `public\en\index.php`. However when I access `http:\\page.craft.dev\en\artists\{slug}` it loads `public\index.php`. So I assume there is a problem with Homestead and nginx?

Comment: I found out that when I access `http:\\page.craft.dev\en\` I am loading `public\en\index.php`. However when I access `http:\\page.craft.dev\en\artists\{slug}` it loads `public\index.php`. So I assume there is a problem with Homestead and nginx?

Comment: Double check your public\en\index.php and public\en\.htaccess files are set up according to [Localization Guide – Step 5](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide#step-5-set-up-the-files)!

Comment: Oh didn't notice you use nginx. Have a look at Brad's recommended config: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/980/125

Comment: Thanks, the issue was the nginx configuration. I hacked it a bit and it started working. Now I will try out config recomended by Brad and choose what works best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appeared to be the nginx config. I updated it according to an example from here ([Locales sub directories on Nginx](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/780/locales-sub-directories-on-nginx)) and it started working.